# Passing Many Parameters for API

Tags: c#, dictionary, argument-passing

I have an API that performs a complex mathematical analysis. The analysis currently involves the calculation of 12 different component values but the number of component values is variable: it will change (likely increase). Components will be added and some may get deleted. Each component requires the specification of a number of parameters (different number for each component). All the parameter values need to be set in order for the analysis to take place.

The API is called through two methods, each of which has an overload.

Method 1: AnaylyzeAll()

This method utilizes all the known components for the analysis, and uses default values for all component parameters.

Method 1 Overload: AnaylyzeAll(componentParameters)

This method utilizes all the known components for the analysis, and uses user specified values to override the default values for select parameters for the components specified.

Method 2: AnaylyzeSelect(componentsToBeAnalyzed)

This method uses the components specified for the analysis, and uses default values for all component parameters.

Method 2 Overload: AnaylyzeSelect(componentsToBeAnalyzed, componentParameters)

This method uses the components specified for the analysis, and uses user values as arguments for select parameters for the components specified.

The componentsToBeAnalyzed is a user-initialized list as follows:

```
internal readonly List<string> componentsToBeAnalyzed = new List<string>()
{
    "ComponentB",
    "ComponentG",
    "ComponentA"
};
```

I was thinking of using the ReadOnlyCollection but as I am targeting .Net 3.5 this may increase complexity.

The componentParameters object is the issue for me. I need to allow the user to specify the component(s) for which the parameters are being provided as well as the parameter values. What I have come up with as a solution is to use an annonymous type array which I then convert to a list, which I then convert to a nested dictionary.

The user provides the following,

```
var componentParameters = new []
{
    new { ComponentName = "ComponentA", ParameterName = "Parameter 1", paramValue = (object)3.247 },
    new { ComponentName = "ComponentA", ParameterName = "Parameter 3", paramValue = (object)"volatile" },
    new { ComponentName = "ComponentA", ParameterName = "Parameter 7", paramValue = (object)Method.Standard },

    new { ComponentName = "ComponentC", ParameterName = "Parameter 2", paramValue = (object)11 },
    new { ComponentName = "ComponentC", ParameterName = "Parameter 5", paramValue = (object)1.145 }
};
```

In the API, I process it as follows

```
var componentInfo = componentParameters.ToList();
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> dict2 = componentInfo
    .GroupBy(x => x.ComponentName)
    .ToDictionary(gComponentName => gComponentName.Key,
                  gComponentName => gComponentName.ToDictionary(t => t.ParameterName,
                                                                t => t.paramValue));
```

My issue is that this does not look like clean and elegant code to me. I have been trying to figure out how to refactor this into something simpler and more effective but have not been able to do so. I would like to also simplify for the user how the parameter values are input. I would like to have something like

```
var componentParameters2 = new object []
{
    new { name = "ComponentA", param1=3.247, param3 = "volatile", param7 = Method.Standard },
    new { name = "ComponentC", param2 = 11, param5 =1.145 }
};
```

But I am not able to convert this to a nested dictionary of the same type as above. Any advice and suggestions on how to best handle this sitution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What if you were to make a class that represents your parameters, ie:

```
public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Parameters[key];
        }
        set
        {
            if(this.Parameters.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                this.Parameters[key] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Parameters.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use it like:

```
var components = new Component
    {
        Name = "ComponentA"
    };

components["parameter1"] = 123;
components["parameter2"] = "volatile";
components["parameter3"] = Method.Standard;

// etc...
```

Maybe this helps?

To solve the syntax issue of wanting it to be succinct, try using the `params` keyword in the constructor.

```
public Component(string name, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] parameters)
{
    Name = name;

    Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>(parameters);
}
```

This will allow the following initialization syntax:

```
var components = new []
    {
        new Component("ComponentA", new []
            {
                { "Parameter1", 123 },
                { "Parameter2", "volatile" },
                { "Parameter3", Method.Standard },
            },
        new Component("ComponentB", new []
            {
                { "Parameter5", 12.25 },
                { "Parameter7", 12 }
            },
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but that will not work in my case. First, I do not want the client to have to make a class in order to pass parameters in. Second, and more importantly, the client may call the API from inside one of his methods and therefore will not be able to create a class inside a method. Finally, this increases the complecity for the user in my opinion.

Comment: Given that your client sounds like it has many stipulations and use cases, you should provide those in your description so we can better tailor solutions to your problems.

Comment: There are no additional stipulations. I am simply looking for a solution - if possible - in which the user does not need to create classes or dictionaries. The simpler the better for the user. I do like the initialization syntax in your last post, even thought it still requires the construction of a class.

Comment: @PBrenek In my opinion, expecting your user to understand that they have to pass a specially formatted anonymous type to your function is far more complex than them having to pass a class or dictionary with known quantities.